# positioning content after div transform

Tags: javascript, jquery, transform, scale

I have content in a div that I am trying to scale according to a user's preferences. I am using [Louis Remi's transform.js](https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.transform.js) to do this.

However, when I do, it pushes the content either way above the top of the div (cutting off content on scale in) or way far down the container (leaving a lot of white space on scale out).

I was wondering if there was anyway that I can push content so that it would affix itself to the top of the div?

Here is a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7VTrL/1/). Right now it is at a .50 scale which shows content being in the middle of the screen leaving a lot of space on top of and bottom of div.

**HTML**

```
<div id="reportContainer">
    <div id="zoomMe">
        <div id="content1" class="fillerBox">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="content2" class="fillerBox">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="content3" class="fillerBox">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="content4" class="fillerBox">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="content5" class="fillerBox">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#reportContainer { margin: 0;padding:15px;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden; border:2px solid black;}
.fillerBox { background-color:#ccc;border:1px dashed #000;height:1500px;width:910px;margin:0 auto;margin-bottom:30px; }
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#reportContainer").height($(window).height()-50);
    $("#zoomMe").css('transform', 'scale(.50)' );
});
```

Comment: scale it to `1` instead of `0.50`

Comment: @ani scaling to 1 is no scale. I'm trying to add a zoom in/out function for users.

Comment: Then the only solution I see is making position: absolute and moving it to right position - for the #zoomme element

Comment: @ani i was hoping you wouldn't say that, but I guess it's not too bad. Right now I have something like `$("#zoomMe").css({ 'transform' : 'scale(.50)', 'top' : '-2280px' });` - have any suggestions on making a "fit" scale option that scales as the container resizes?

Comment: Not on the top of my head. here's a simple example: Use windowrezise function and calculate the height using total height and window height ratio. make sense ?

Comment: That makes sense, I found a ratio that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A nice person on one of my other questions actually answered this, but since someone up-voted my question I guess I will put it here as well.

There is a great CSS option to append a transformed element. This is what I ended up doing thanks to the help of a fellow stackoverflow'r.

```
-webkit-transform-origin: top center;
-moz-transform-origin: top center;
transform-origin: top center;
```